# Huge analog switching matrix

Tags: pcb, switches, routing, matrix

My application is a PCB that has 2 different 100 pins connectors and has to be capable of arbitrarily connect each pin on the first connector to each pin of the second.

The signal going through the board, once ALL the connections are set, will be on only a subset (4) lines at any given time and will be in the DC-20 Hz band at a maximum of 1mA @ 0.1V. Cross-talk is not to be considered in this application.

I have to change the configuration once in a while and when I have to do that I can access the board manually. Active components (like MUXes) are discouraged because the signals are used for cryogenic 4-wires measures and the cost of suitable components quickly becomes inaccessible.

My original solutions have been:

- Using a set of DIP SPST switches to build the connection matrix
- Using a lot of small (16mm^2) push-down buttons to build the connection matrix

Both this solutions are expensive and space consuming. I was wondering if anyone knows a better component for this application.

The need for flexibility comes from the deployment environment of the application. Once (and if) this component is deployed in the field (South pole station) and set I won't have access to it for ~1y. So in 3 months I'll spend there I'll have to make sure everything works and there's the possibility I'll have to reroute some channels. The good old hydra cable soldering is not reliable, thus I was exploring other solutions.

Comment: Probably I should remove the 4 pins detail. It was to clarify that cross-talk is a very minor problem in this application as, once ALL the connections are set, only four lines at time are used.

Comment: yes. and then use some control (mechanical in my solutions) to decide which pin is connected to which.

Comment: That detail is the difference between \$100^{100}\$ possible configurations and \$25^{25}\$, which is still an astounding number, but if you are willing to constrain the possible connections a bit more you might start to get close to something tractable.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a lookup table (LUT). I don’t personally know of mechanical versions these days but I know they were used in the early days of computers. If someone can’t point you in a better direction or to something more specific, I would read up on LUTs and see where it takes you.

Comment: The number of buttons needed, for example, was a 100*100 matrix. So that in order to connect pin, say, 1 to pins 2 and 3 of the other connector I have to push two buttons.

Comment: Any reason not to just solder in jumpers from one connector to the other, and make a separate plugboard for each connection configuration?

Comment: 10000 audio plugs arranged in 100x100 matrix with 100 shorted audio jacks ........ two breadboards stacked on top of each other and turned 90 degrees with long pins that pass through the back of the top breadboard into the bottom breadboard ... expanded to 100x100

Comment: Using cables for switching the signal crossed my mind. Not elegant but practical. Until you need to scale up the design and you end up with 3 or 4 of these and then the cables don't fit in the board anymore...

Comment: I wouldn’t do it with breadboard, but that’s sort of what I imagined.

Comment: I need 100 output because I am interfacing with a bunch of other instruments and all has to be connected. The other instruments (LS370 lakeshore) use a time multiplexed scheme to read all the channels.

Comment: something is missing ... are you switching 25 probes?

Comment: The LS370 does a measure (say every 4 seconds) using 4 of the connections I'm trying to manage. Than does the same using a different channel (other 4 connections) and so on in a loop.

Comment: what I'm looking for is something that looks like this http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2250923.pdf
but entirely passive. In the case above the on-resistance is not acceptable

Comment: @Oznerol If you needs something that is functionally equivalent, you will need 100×100 switching things. That will be absolutely no fun. (think of a 1940 telephone switchroom. Employees making connections in front of giant boards.) However, your "four at a time" constraint makes this a lot more tractable (still not small). Got any more of these constraints? Tell us about the requirements, more, not less!

Comment: @Oznerol also, I'm kind of confused that you think plugging cables (with all the noise pickup a plugged cable can have, and all the unwanted semiconductor junction that a corroded metal-metal contact can be) is better than good active analog switches? You should really tell us more about the overall thing you want to build, the signals, bandwidths, voltages, ,the measurements,...

Comment: At some point you need to ask yourself whether it might make more sense to just put 25 copies of the measurement circuit on your custom board and multiplex the output data digitally.

Comment: If you want to do a 4 terminal measurement with your LS370 on a bunch of different sensors in a sequence why are we talking about a 100 to 100 mapping? Dont you just need 4 to 100 (assuming 25 temp sensors)? Do you have multiple (25?) LS370s that need to be able to do the measurement?

Comment: _"in order to connect pin, say, 1 to pins 2 and 3 of the other connector"_ - why would you want to connect 1 pin to 2 others? You say _'2 different 100 pins connectors... **arbitrarily** connect **each** pin on the first connector to **each** pin of the second'_, but also  _'4-wires measures'_ which suggests groups of 4 wires, each wire of the group in a defined order. So is it really 25 x 4 wire connections?

Comment: Can you not reprogram the "LS370" so it reads the channels in a different order and avoids the whole switching thing?

Comment: Why don't you *specify* in the question that the purpose is to do 25 different 4-wire resistance measurements? Then, we can think of good ways to do 25 different 4-wire resistance measurements, which don't involve huge analog switching arrays! Unless you're dead set on making a huge array just for the coolness factor, which you should not be since this is going to the south pole.

Comment: @Oznerol you said "...does a measure (say every 4 seconds) using 4 of the connections...Than does the same using a different channel (other 4 connections) and so on in a loop.". Well then first a switch matrix with 200 Switches x4 Layers should be capable to do the job, but must be switched every 4sec according of your sequence. And stuff like this you get of the shelf e.g. for automated testing PXI chassis. Plus a automated test will not do errors when turning the switches. 10000 manual switches doesn't sound like a good idea to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the freshly added info:

> The need for flexibility comes from the deployment environment of the application. Once (and if) this component is deployed in the field (South pole station) and set I won't have access to it for ~1y. So in 3 months I'll spend there I'll have to make sure everything works and there's the possibility I'll have to reroute some channels. The good old hydra cable soldering is not reliable, thus I was exploring other solutions.

Well, this sounds like you should bring a soldering iron to the South Pole, some solder wick and solder:

Make a square board, with the input connector on the "north" edge of the board, from it extending 100 columns.

The output connector on the "west" edge, from it extending 100 rows.

Add 100 "solder jumpers", i.e. connections you can make with solder (and unmake with a wick), from each row (10,000 in total), and from the "free" end of these, place a via to the underlying column.

That way, you get a pretty inflexible (as in: soldering tools needed to reconfigure), but magnificently reliable connection matrix.

Comment: No, soldering is not an option. If anything happens I cannot ask someone there to take out a board and solder it. The idea tho is nice. I'm looking into a matrix of pin headers and a bunch of jumpers to make the contacts. It's simpler than DIP switches or relays and cheaper.

Comment: in that case: SMD Pin headers are a thing, allowing you to make that board more compact / add more silkscreen labeling to it. DIP switches might mechanically be easier to deal with (using a small screwdriver, pencil etc) than removing a jumper, dropping it, then bumping your head on a table while looking for it on the ground (don't ask me how I've earned an opinion on this specific topic ;) )

Comment: I'll start a design with headers pin. Though hole instead of SMD may spare some via here and there. This definitively helped me out in approaching this problem. Thanks.
DIP switches are quite expensive and big for this.

Answer (score 1):

So, when you say

> 100 pins connectors and has to be capable of arbitrarily connect each pin on the first connector to each pin of the second.

and imagine one connector to be an input vector \$U\in \mathbb F^{100}\$, the other to be a result vector \$V \in \mathbb F^{100}\$, then your whole device would need to be a 100×100 permutation matrix \$\Pi\in \mathbb F^{100\times 100}\$. (i.e. a matrix where each row and column has a single unity element, the rest being zero):

$$V=\Pi U\tag1\label{full}$$

You can straightforward implement that using any kind of switches.

And such a matrix has 10,000 entries that can be 0 or 1 – i.e. 10⁴ switches; relays that you control from a PC would probably be wisest, simply to avoid human error.

Now, you say:

> The signal going through the board, once ALL the connections are set, will be on only a subset (4) lines at any given time

Well, that makes it easier:

Instead of having \$\eqref{full}\$, you can imagine an intermediate result vector \$W\in \mathbb F^{4}\$.

If you don't even "blow this back up" to the full 100 outputs in \$V\$, and I don't see a reason for that, your measurement devices doesn't seem to care whether it scans 100 channels or just the 4, that boils down to

$$\tilde V = \mathbf PU,$$

with \$\mathbf P\in  \mathbb F^{100\times 4}\$, i.e. only 400 switches instead of 10,000.

If you can further restrict that (for example, there's only specific index subsets from which the first of your four outputs can come), then you might further simplify the problem: For example, four 25×1 matrices are still way easier than one 100×4 one!

An order of 400 switches still isn't cheap, and now you'll have to switch dynamically when you want to measure a different 4-set of channels. However, signal relays (exactly for *switched-circuit telephony* historical reasons) are comparatively cheap ([A list](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/relays/signal-relays-up-to-2-amps/189?k=&pkeyword=&sv=0&sf=0&FV=-8%7C189&quantity=400&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=25)).

Considering coil voltages and currents of [5 V, 40 mA typ.](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/cit-relay-and-switch/J104D2C5VDC-20S/2449-J104D2C5VDC-20S-ND/12503179), you might just directly drive these off open-drain or open-collector shift registers for a couple of cents, e.g. [STPIC6D595](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/e5/1c/d3/4a/66/f5/41/dc/CD00163738.pdf/files/CD00163738.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00163738.pdf), which you can in turn directly attach to a 5V bitbang/SPI-driver (which exist either as microcontrollers or as USB-to-SPI converters, for example).

Rough calculation of the board you'll need: The relay I linked to has an area of 11×21 mm², and you need a 10×6 mm² shift register for every 8 relays.

That makes a total area of 400·231 mm² + 50·60 mm² = 95400 mm². If you're a bit symmetrical about arranging the 8 relays head-to-head and the shift register at the end of each such row, you end up with a ca 17 cm wide board; if you put 32 rows on a board, that will be, including auxillary things (connectors etc) be 40 cm tall. Manufactured in China, five boards of [that](https://cart.jlcpcb.com/quote?orderType=1&stencilWidth=170&stencilLength=400&stencilCounts=5&stencilLayer=2&stencilPly=1.6&steelmeshSellingPriceRecordNum=A8256537-5522-491C-965C-646F5842AEC9&purchaseNumber=) size will set you back by ca 40 to 80€ incl. shipping.

Adding 440 relays and 55 shift registers (10% overorder in case you damage anything) for about 300 € (not including taxes); throw in 50€ for connectors, power supply, LEDs and stuff, this is a 400€ project.

Compare that to the 10,000 switches: rather cheap and easy!

(in case you're a PhD candidate physicist or similar: get a student research assistant to design, and assemble, and test, and write a minimal control software for that board. Pay her or him well, i.e. overprovision her hours if necessary. These kinds of devices, if done well, usually have long-term utility after the end of your PhD. Add a sticker to it that points to some public documentation, and put all design files under CERN's [open hardware license v2](https://ohwr.org/project/cernohl/wikis/Documents/CERN-OHL-version-2), and put everything on the internet, e.g. github, so that the next physicist doesn't reinvent the wheel. People have been cited for less in other people's papers!)

Comment: Thanks for the very complete reply. Although there are very good ideas in your solution, I don't think this is a solution I can use for two reasons:
- Placing any non specialized active component on the board will cause the measures done by the LS370 to not be reliable (tested with some active filter and a Stanford research amplifier) because of the impedance introduced (200Ohm typical with large variation) and the electrical noise introduced.
- 4 lines are read at one time after ALL the connections are set and I need complete flexibility 100x25 matrix.

Comment: I'd hardly call a relay an "active component". It's really just a switch, with the switch being mechanically actuated by an electromagnet. That has no effect on your current. I don't know where you take the 200 Ω from? Why do you need full flexibility? Setting all your relays will take less than 10 ms. So you can reconfigure your relay board on the fly as often as you like.

Comment: (I really think you might be misunderstanding what a relay is!)

Comment: my bad, confused by many tabs open. The relays are a good solution as long as I have electronics for controlling them (as you point out) and thus the need for some noisy active component, power supply and so on. I'm looking for something completely passive, mechanically controlled. That said I'll invest some time investigating the possibilities, this may turn out to be still the best solution.

Comment: Well, I don't see why the relay coils and shift registers would introduce any noise – you're operating them with an arbitrarily low-noise DC source (e.g. a car battery), and also, your own words state "cross-talk is assumed to be negligible", and the very same applies to these currents, which unlike your other signals are not *meant* to fluctuate. The only point where there would be noise is during switching. There's also bistable relays, which you can completely power off after switching; they're a tiny bit more expensive, but would totally devalue your argument (which is good for you :) )

Comment: The need for flexibility comes from the deployment environment of the application. Once (and if) this component is deployed in the field (South pole station) and set I won't have access to it for ~1y. So in 3 months I'll spend there I'll have to make sure everything works and there's the possibility I'll have to reroute some channels. The good old hydra cable soldering is not reliable, thus I was exploring other solutions.

Comment: Note that you were willing to accept flying wires as an alternative, so you definitely have some leeway for pickup for stray electromagnetic fields, or you're not modelling your noise correctly ;)

Comment: well, that comment would be a good addition to your question!

Comment: I should point out that reliability is fundamental. Bistable relays are very close to what I'm looking for. Let me run some search, hopefully this is it.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that I'd use as the prime candidate to compare others against is one which you mentioned in a comment

> I'm looking into a matrix of pin headers and a bunch of jumpers to make the contacts. It's simpler than DIP switches or relays and cheaper.

While this is not as elegant as a somewhat more automated solution it may be as good or better in practice.

Given the large number of inputs and outputs, the infrequent requirement for change and the apparently non time critical nature of the connection alteration a jumper and header solution sounds very workable. Also cheap, easy and compact (choose any 3) compared to obvious alternatives.

[image]

These are available in various lengths and with either polarity plugs and sockets at each end. While the low cost Asian sourced ones seem to work commendably well in general use you'd need to obtain such from a source with known contact materials and supplier and manufacturer provenance. [Digikey is generally a good source of genuine product - but certainly not the only source.].

Long term connection reliability is obviously an issue.
Your signal specification of "DC-20 Hz band at a maximum of 1mA @ 0.1V." means "contact wetting" needs to be addressed. Many materials exhibit high or even extremely high contact resistance at low currents. You'll need to examine the properties of specific contact materials for suitability.  This is an area that competent connector manufacturers are well versed in and technical help will be readily available. "Off the cuff" gold-gold should work well BUT do check this yourself.

**__________________________________**

Possibly tolerable alternatives are screw down connections where the screw tightening action provides low contact resistance, or  DIN rail connectors with screw down connections. Costs and volume are not as low as for the jumper connections but still modest compared to the value of your project.

[Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=din+rail+connectors&rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&oq=din+rail+connector&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l6.7246j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) are links to a zillion DIN rail; connectors.

[Here](https://nz.element14.com/phoenix-contact/3044076/terminal-block-din-rail-2pos-12awg/dp/8332975?gclid=CjwKCAjwnef6BRAgEiwAgv8mQfytuIo91lCdEQvHgiE9rH_leugd_Gfq6xad8kaYqGKKvWZ4WY1BdhoCaMMQAvD_BwE&mckv=_dc%7Cpcrid%7C399474782117%7Cpkw%7C%7Cpmt%7C%7Cslid%7C%7Cproduct%7C8332975%7Cpgrid%7C86460843753%7Cptaid%7Cpla-298884436745%7C&CMP=KNC-GOO-SHOPPING-8332975) ius an Element 14 page for a Phoenix contacts DIN rail connector - $1.56 each in 250 quantity. Cheaper elsewhere probably.

3.2 mV drop at 24A if I read the datasheet correctly. (Caveat Emptor).

[Datasheet here](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2309860.pdf?_ga=2.119934539.2108063291.1599734765-1610921226.1597625160&_gac=1.195694046.1599734765.CjwKCAjwnef6BRAgEiwAgv8mQfytuIo91lCdEQvHgiE9rH_leugd_Gfq6xad8kaYqGKKvWZ4WY1BdhoCaMMQAvD_BwE)

[image]

**____________________________________**

If you REALLY wanted to save money you could have 100 + 100 wires with suitably terminated ends and 4 only connector blocks :-).

The above use screwdriver implemented termination.

You can get hold button - insert wire - release button versions which *may* be easier to use in polar conditions. Or lever release versions - image below. From [here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Terminal-Connector-Compact-Wiring-Randomly/dp/B07VRPTM8M) - NB example only. NOT a recommendation re brand.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have built a board before that is similar to what you are describing.

Each pin on connector #1 connects to four solid state relays.  Each of the four relays connects to one of four nets A, B, C, D.  Thus any pin can be connected to either net A, B, C, D.

The same thing is done for connector #2.

Since you have four nets A, B, C, D you can connect any arbitrary combination of up to four pins on one connector, to any set of four pins on the other connector.

The total number of relays needed is 800.  If its low current and low voltage, you may get 800 relays for under $1000.  If its higher voltage or current then you may pay closer to $10,000.

To drive the relays you can use a latching shift register relay driver such as the TLC59281DBQR (which is under $1.00 each).  You would need 50 of those to drive 800 relays.

The setup doesn't consume that much power since you only need 8 of the relay on at any one time.  Depending on which relay drivers you pick they can consume micro-amps.  And you can get a low power micro-controler consuming under 1 mA to power the whole thing.

If you need any test signals you can throw on a few more relays that connect test signals to any of the A, B, C, D nets.

If you really want to do it mechanically, you could do the exact same setup with buttons or toggle switches instead of relays.

Answer (score 0):

An off the shelf Relay matrix board will solve your problem. Relays are passive, some of these boards use latching relays, so the routes maintain state even when the controller is not powered.
Since you are switching signals and not power, a reed relay matrix is also a viable solution.
You can get such boards from the usual suspects (Tek, Keysight, NI).